What does "the next" refer to?
Alice discusses Gilbert's unwavering political beliefs
and her own lack of certainty with wagon train leader
Billy Knapp, who kindly reassures her that this trait is
not a defect at all:

Billy Knapp: Uncertainty...That is appropriate for matters
of this world. Only regarding the next are we vouchsafed
certainty.

What does "the next" refer to ?

Following 'this world', the 'next world' (where some people believe we go after we die). Example of ellipsis (omission of words where they do not affect the meaning for a native reader). Only devoutly religious people believe we are 'vouchsafed certainty' about what (if anything) happens to our conscious self after death. I suspect the remark is a rather dry joke.


Uncertainty...That is appropriate for matters of this world. Only regarding the next are we vouchsafed certainty.

The next contrasts with this world.    It means the next world.
Google defines the next world:

(according to some religious beliefs) the place where one goes after death.


Or in completely plain language: “The only thing that’s certain is that we all die”.

@JanusBahsJacquet I think in context (given the Oregon Trail context, presumably a Christian speaker) it's better read as "the only thing that's certain is the Christian afterlife, where good Christians are saved and go to Heaven". The difference being, I guess, I think that the speaker sees the promise of certainty about the next life as a source of comfort.

@Kaia Entirely possible – I don’t know who any of the people are, and didn’t realise it was Oregon Trail–related.
